# Lucene: Similarity class... how to define several similarity measures?

Tags: java, lucene

For my experiment I need to define specific similarity metrics for each field of my collection documents.

For example, I need to measure the Description field similarity with tf.idf, and Geolocation fields with Harvesine distance.. etc...

I'm now studying the Similarity class. I was wondering if there is any good tutorial or example about this to procede faster...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
IIUC, you have a similarity formula per field, and you want to use it per document, running against all other documents.
You can use several options, all at indexing time:

1. Extend the [DefaultSimilarity](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/DefaultSimilarity.html) class.
2. Extend the [SimilarityDelegator](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/SimilarityDelegator.html) class, if you only need to modify part of the methods.

In both methods, you may make use of [payloads](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2010/04/18/refresh-getting-started-with-payloads/) to store term-specific information (could be useful for the lat-long data).

After implementing a Similarity class using one of these methods, use Similarity.setDefault(mySimilarity) to set this as the Similarity instance for indexing and searching.

Only then index your text corpus, which you can search later - you will probably have to extend the Searcher class as well to get the raw similarity.

Having said that, I believe this approach is wrong for your use case - Lucene is optimized to get a few similar documents, not a score for every one, so I predict the runtime will be prohibitive - Hope I am wrong, but nevertheless I suggest you read [Mining of Massive Datasets](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds.html) for a better approach - min hashes and shingling.

Good luck.

<strike>Patrick, I will first quote Grant Ingersoll about modifying the Similarity class: ["Here be Dragons"](http://lucene-eurocon.org/slides/Practical-Relevance_Grant-Ingersoll.pdf). Customizing Lucene's Similarity class is hard. I have done this. 
It is not fun. Only do this if you absolutely have to.</strike>

I suggest you should first read [Grant's spatial search paper](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/j-spatial/index.html), [his findability paper](http://www.lucidimagination.com/Community/Hear-from-the-Experts/Articles/Optimizing-Findability-Lucene-and-Solr) and [his 'debugging relevance' paper](http://www.lucidimagination.com/Community/Hear-from-the-Experts/Articles/Search-Application-Relevance-Issues). These show other ways to get hits as needed.

Comment: @Yuval F The material you passed me is not exactly what I'm looking for. I don't need to refine Lucene documents score or Findability. Also, I don't need info about location aware service (it is interesting though). What I need to know is how to integrate multiple similarity measures into one: lucene already has a tf-idf score I can use for some fields. For other fields such as lat-long I need to use Harvesine distance (I already have a formula to use)...

Comment: @Patrick - Can you please elaborate? Do you need similarity to rank documents in a Lucene fashion, or do you need it for another purpose, say as a feature to compare documents?

Comment: @Yuval F ok. I'm going to use as query a document of the collection in order to compare it to all other docs. So it is to compare documents. Each document has text fields, geo fields, and time/date field. I need to average the scores over all fields. I want to use my own scores formulas for geo and time/date. It is ok to use tf/idf for other fields instead.

Comment: Here's my 2c: If your collection is not very small, this is not a good use of Lucene. Lucene's similarity is planned to extract a few similar documents, rather than compare to all other documents. I suggest you use Weka or Mahout's clustering for this. I will edit my answer along these lines.

Comment: @Yuval F I would like to give a try beacause my docs are very short. But what I actually need is to define different similarity measures per field. Can you help me ?

Comment: @Yuval F Thanks for updating the answer. However, in my question I've already mentioned the Similarity class. The issue with the similarity class is that only computeNorm(),lengthNorm() and scorePayload() have field as input parameter. Therefore I cannot customize the score per field level but only per document level.